# Facebook login API not working

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm receiving the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

The application URL is https://mysubdomain.herokuapp.com/social/login

In FB App settings...

**Basic settings**
[image: Basic settings]

**Advanced settings**
[image: Advanced settings]

**Error received**
[image: Error received]

---

I'm able to get Google+ and Twitter working, but Facebook is being stubborn. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the App Domain and Redirect URI, and it started working. I'm not sure if this is a safe/smart approach, but it at least got things working.